# Issue with Running powershell on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, user-profile-service, time-out

Hi I am facing an issue while running powershell script. we have total of 20,000 users. after processing for 3 and half hour . I got the below error

```
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The HTTP service located at http://tetsjhsjsj22222/MetadataWebService.svc is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later."



  #Importing PowerShell Module
    Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking


#Authenticating User to SharePoint Online
   $username = "test@domainO365Dev.onmicrosoft.com" 
   $Adminurl = "https://sp-admin.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev"
   $siteColUrl = "https://test365dev.sharepoint.com"

#Logging Method for errors
   $DATE = get-date
   $LogPath = "logpath"
   $LogFileName = "LogFileName.log"

$FilePath = $LogPath +"\" + $LogFileName
$logFileCreated = $False
function write-log([string]$label, [string]$logMsg)
{ 

    if($logFileCreated -eq $False)
    {
        write-host "Creating log file..."
        if((Test-Path -path $LogPath) -ne $True)
        {
            write-host"Provide proper values to LogPath folder" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        else
        {
            Add-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $logHeader
            $script:logFileCreated  = $True
            write-host "Log file created..."
            [string]$info = [System.String]::Format("[$Date] {0}: {1}",$label, $logMsg)
            Add-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $info
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [string]$info = [System.String]::Format("[$Date] {0}: {1}",$label, $logMsg)
        Add-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $info
    }
 }

try
{
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll"
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"


   #Bind to site collection
   $password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString 
   $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteColUrl)
   $Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,$Password)
   $Context.Credentials = $Creds
   Write-Host "Successfully connected.." -ForegroundColor Green


   #Retrieve lists
   $web = $Context.Web
   $Users = $Context.Web.SiteUsers
   $Context.Load($Users)
   $Context.Load($web)
   $Context.ExecuteQuery()

   $PeopleManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($Context)
    Foreach ($User in $Users)
    {  
      $UserProfile = $PeopleManager.GetPropertiesFor($User.LoginName)
      Write-Host "user profile value: " + $UserProfile
      $Context.ExecuteQuery()
      If ($UserProfile.Email -ne $null)
        {
          Write-Host "User:" $UserProfile.Email -ForegroundColor Green
          $UserProfile.UserProfileProperties

          //processing read data from list loop through 50 items
        }  
    }
}
  catch
       { 
          write-log "Error: " $_.Exception.Message
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any number of things could happen to interrupt a process like this that is being executed against the service via PowerShell. I would break the users into batches of 50 or 100 and add error handling to recover when a batch aborts in the middle.

More importantly, I would ask why you need to manually fix up the email address of those user accounts? If they are not in sunc with the source (Azure AD, on-prem, AD) I would troubleshoot the sync pipeline rather than try to path them manually. If it is a sync issue then when that gets fixed it will just plow over your changes anyway.